# Selenium webdriver cannot reach button (manually too)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a problem with Selenium. In a normal browser (Firefox, Chrome) I can go to a page and click a button. In Selenium browser (Chrome) - I can't. Also - I can't even do it manually in Selenium Chrome. The button does not respond. What could be the cause of this?

Edit: I'd like to send some message. I filled data, but I still have a problem with sending it (button is clicked, but message is not sent) I provided CAPS LOCK comment in my code where the problem is.

I mean black button (Abschicken) example url: https://home.mobile.de/sample#contact

Any help would be greatly appreciated

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), desired_capabilities=caps)

browser.get('https://home.mobile.de/sample#contact')
time.sleep(5)
# Closing popup
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sc-bczRLJ iBneUr mde-consent-accept-btn']").click()

user_name = browser.find_element_by_name("name")
user_mail = browser.find_element_by_name("email")
user_message = browser.find_element_by_id("contactText")

time.sleep(0.7)
user_name.send_keys("example name")

time.sleep(0.7)
user_mail.send_keys("example@mail.com")

time.sleep(0.7)
user_message.send_keys("My message. Good morning sir")   

browser.find_element_by_name("sendCopyToMe").click()
# Clicking ##### BUT IT NOT CAUSE SENDING A MESSAGE @@@@@
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-inverse span20 contactSend']").click()
```

Comment: Manually - I mean that I run selenium webdriver and click manually there. In normal webbrowser everything works fine.

Comment: @Prophet - I've tried your solution. But after completing a form there are no email sent :(

Comment: Mr. @Prophet, do you have any other sugestions? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe. But you asked only about clicking that button. You did not fill data in a form etc before that.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I should write about it. My aim is to send an e-mail with Selenium - everything works fine (filling data also) but not clicking a button :(

Comment: If so please share all your existing code here.

Comment: Full code provided in main question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251034/discussion-between-martin-domino-and-prophet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not share your code, not the error you received.
So I don't know what you did wrong.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://home.mobile.de/AUTOMOBILE-WIERSCHEM#contact"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*=accept]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*=contactSend]"))).click()
```

Comment: Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: This code perfrorms what you asked in this question. For additional questions  I will probably have additional recomendations

Comment: Ok, so could you give ma a hint how to deal with send a complete message on that website with selenium?

Comment: I can try help you later, after the work. If possible open a new question for that where you will describe what exactly have you tried and what exactly problems have you faced, what exactly not working, what errors you faced etc. Maybe other people will answer you before I will have a time, that's OK too.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I cannot create a new post - I have a low reputation :( I'll wait for you. Now I wonder is it a fault of webdriver or my code? It's first time that I faced problem like this.

Comment: OK, but again. I have no idea what is your code and what not worked there. You can edit this question to add all that information

Comment: I posted some new informations and my code (a line before last is a comment what is not working). Is it clear now?

Comment: OK, I see. Now I really see this is not working even manually. So, it's not question about Selenium code that is not working. Maybe that page / site is not working or maybe you need to fill more data there, I don't know

Comment: It's working in normal website, but not in selenium webdriver :( Do you have any idea?

Comment: If so, this maybe some kind of anti-bot defence. I have no experience with such things, I'm sorry